# How to run cuda cooperative template kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-cooperative-groups

I am trying to unsuccessfully launch template kernel as cooperative kernel in CUDA C++ , what am I doing wrong

error

```
Error       cannot determine which instance of function template "boolPrepareKernel" is intended
```

I try to invoke kernel like below

```
 ForBoolKernelArgs<int> fbArgs = ...;

    int device = 0;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, device);
   cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)boolPrepareKernel, deviceProp.multiProcessorCount, fFArgs.threads, fbArgs) ;
```

kernel is defined like

```
template <typename TYO>
__global__ void boolPrepareKernel(ForBoolKernelArgs<TYO> fbArgs) {
...
}
```

I tried parametrarize launch (in this example with int) like

```
    cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)(<int>boolPrepareKernel), deviceProp.multiProcessorCount, fFArgs.threads, fbArgs) ;
```

but I get error

```
no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list            argument types are: (<error-type>, int, dim3, ForBoolKernelArgs<int>)
```

For suggested case

```
cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)(boolPrepareKernel<int>), deviceProp.multiProcessorCount, fFArgs.threads, fbArgs)
```

My error is

```
 no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list            argument types are: (void *, int, dim3, ForBoolKernelArgs<int>)
```

This is probably sth simple but I am stuck - thanks for help !!

For reference kernel launch like

```
boolPrepareKernel << <fFArgs.blocks, fFArgs.threads >> > (fbArgs);
```

works but of course grid synchronization is unavailable.

Comment: `<int>boolPrepareKernel` seems wrong, why not `boolPrepareKernel<int>`?

Comment: Thanks but error remains as I edited in the main question

Comment: This won't work: `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)boolPrepareKernel,...` You need to indicate which template specialization you want there.  I also suggest providing a [mcve] rather than a bunch of snippets.  It will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks ! @RobertCrovella  exactly this is what I want to do - How to indicate that I want to specialize it to int

Comment: The [prototype](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g504b94170f83285c71031be6d5d15f73) for `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel` includes argument types as: `( const void* func, dim3 gridDim, dim3 blockDim, void** args, size_t sharedMem, cudaStream_t stream )`  Your error message has indicated that the arguments you are passing don't match those types, in that order.  Why not make your arguments match the intended types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example that will compile:

```
$ cat t1954.cu
template <typename TYO>
struct ForBoolKernelArgs
{
    TYO val;
};

template <typename TYO>
__global__ void boolPrepareKernel(ForBoolKernelArgs<TYO> fbArgs) {
}


int main(){
  ForBoolKernelArgs<int> fbArgs;
  void *kernel_args[] = {&fbArgs};
  cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)(boolPrepareKernel<int>), 1, 1, kernel_args) ;
}
$ nvcc -o t1954 t1954.cu
$
```

Probably the main issue you had remaining is that you are not following proper [instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization-cg) for passing kernel arguments.